# Suppress messages with Content-Disposition header to file output

Tags: php, output, content-disposition

When someone calls a URL, I want to post him/her a .csv file.  This works with Content-Disposition headers.  However, I would like to tell php in my program when it should start with the output and when it should ignore messages being otherwise printed to the screen.

The reason is that I am calling general classes that lookup data in a database (a CRM).  These lookup function 'must' generate some output.  The reason for this is that they take longer than 1 minute (sometimes) and the output is like a 'ping' telling browsers not to close the connection and wait for the completion of the script.
I do not want this output in my csv-file, though.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);

header('Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=search.csv');
....
ob_start();

//these two methods can take a long time and they 'ping' between pages
//i.e. after they looked up 450 records, they ping and look up the next 450
$allPublished=OrganizationLookups::lookup(["ORGANISATION_FIELD_4" => 
    "true"],$myInsightly);
$allContacts=ContactLookups::lookup(["TAGS" => "TPZ-Mieter"],$myInsightly);
//flush and ob_end_clean was my idea to suppress the output
//but it does not work
flush();ob_flush();
ob_end_clean();

//now i am ready to put everything to the file what comes next
$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
....
   fputcsv($file,$itarray); //in foreach loop
}
fclose($file);
exit();
?>
```

As you can see in the code, I am trying to fiddle with ob_start() etc. to control the output, but it does not work. (I also tried ob_get_clean etc)
I also would think that only stuff written to the $file (php://output) is written to the csv file, but it prints everything into it.

Comment: If they ping, wouldn't they send the ping already to browser i.e. flush the output? In that case only a redesign of your application could help you.

Comment: Would JavaScript dependency and / or reload be an option? IE/Edge/Fox shouldn't have big problems with long polling, only Opera was reported to have some issue.

Comment: The 'ping' is necessary because the OrganizationLookups class etc. are used in different 'tools', not only for the csv-file abstract.  But apparently, there is no simple 'trick' to tell the app to put the data to the file or not, so I will work around with a 'silent' parameter being taken in the lookup functions.

Comment: What do you actually mean with the term 'ping'?

Comment: So, it is not clear what is output by 'ping' and why you are trying to prevent the output by buffering. The data sent should prevent the browser from closing the connection.

Comment: Since multipart responses seem to be differently supported by browsers, we could find an alternative approach. You only want to download generated data, not necessarily within the same request but automatically initiated as a subsequent request when ready, right? Using JavaScript is an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be a multipart reply showing an HTML page and providing a file download. However, there seem to be support issues by some browser(s), especially Chrome.

```
<?php  declare (strict_types=1);
  header('Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT');
  header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
  header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  header('Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="MultiPartBoundary"');
?>

--MultiPartBoundary
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Download</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>search.cvs - Download</h1>
  <div>
    generating CVS
<?php  // fake generation showing progress
  for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
  {
    sleep(1);
    echo '.' . str_repeat(' ', 1024), PHP_EOL;
    flush();
  }
?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
--MultiPartBoundary
Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=search.csv

<?php   // CVS output
echo <<< __EOS__
Col1,Col2,Col3
Val11,Val12,Val13
Val21,Val22,Val23

__EOS__;
?>

--MultiPartBoundary--
```

I used `.htaccess` to disable buffering

```
<Files "multipart.php">
    php_value output_buffering Off
</Files>
```

**Alternatives**

There are more commonly used approaches based on JavaScript. Basically the principle is always the same: You perform an initiating request and the generation is started in the background. Subsequent requests, e.g. AJAX or simple reloads, ask for the data with a temporary ID.

Another more complex alternative is to implement a bidirectional websocket connection with a real server-push functionality.

Comment: I just copy'n' pasted your headers with no further check for plausibility, even overwriting previous ones. Not sure, but I guess cache control on the single parts is ignored at all.

Comment: Hi Quasimodo.  sorry, I was offline.  This is exactly what would solve my problem.  I will try this out to see if it works.  Sorry for the term 'ping' being imprecise, but I did not know how to describe it and you guessed correctly, what I mean ;)

Comment: Do you or someone know if these multipart repsonses are supported by browsers (e.g. Chrome?).  When I now call the page, I get the whole response saved to a file having the file part in the URL as its name.  The response looks correct with the boundaries and headers.   Forum posts from 2012 or so suggest that browser would not support multipart responses, but maybe this has changed.  "Content-Disposition: render" in the first part also did not make a difference

Comment: @user3117071 Which browsers did you try? The above was tested in fixefox and worked properly. The headers and boundaries have to be exact, i.e. they have to be at column 0 and there must be CR+LF characters with an empty line to seperate content. The RFC recommendaten that single LF characters should be relaxed interpreted as newline sequence as well, most browers also comply with. The LF (ASCII 10) is mandatory.

Comment: Actually there seems to be an issue with chromium browser / debian (the editor might have saved LF only). Fox exactly behaves as expected, Edge/IE not tested.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I can confirm that it works with perfectly with firefox, but not with Chrome.  The editor I used may have saved LF only, but I changed this